# How to add a IBM Watson Assistant chatbot on to a webpage?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to add my chatbot to a webpage but cannot use the IBM cli for this due to me not having admin rights on my system for install. I have eclipse as an IDE and cannot find good documentation for the above mentioned integration.

Comment: CLI for what? Do you have provisioned the service? What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure we understand your question. I take it that you have used the IBM Assistant tooling to create a Chat bot. You may have also used the Assistant "Preview" Skill to view how your chat bot works. Currently to then get your chat-bot onto your web page you need to develop an application that can be executed on your site. There are examples of this on IBM DeveloperWorks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the IBM Cloud CLI (if that's what you're referring to).

What you need:
1. Provision a service instance of Watson Assistant in your IBM Cloud account

2. Get API key from your Watson Assistant service instance. Go to the IBM Cloud Dashboard, look for your Watson Assistant service, there look for "credentials". It should mention an API key and e.g. correct URL.
3. Get the Watson SDK for your programming language of choice (e.g. Java):
   Follow the docs on how to configure the SDK and make calls:
   https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2?code=java#introduction

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for not being clear. My major problem was getting this thing to work due to there being problems with the latest java sdk (7.1.1) so instead had to use version 7.0.0 from the official GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Watson Assistant has now rolled out a new update, where you can find embeddable links for the chatbot and embedd them as iframes in your website, if the ask is to create a simple chatbot. Attaching the pictures below.

And so one wouldn't actually need to develop a full fledged backend, incase the chatbot functions are simple and even if they are complex, one can simply use IBM Cloud functions for a serverless app deployment.

[image: Integrations Page]

[image: IFRAME embeddable Chatbot Link]

Hope this helps.